# How to "translate" in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have been trying to beat this problem for some time. I have been given a "dictionary" with translations. The assignment is that i am going to use this dictionary for the purpose of translating words.
example: "thanks" = "danke"
The only requirment for this problem is that the type is that it is not allowed to import things like Data.list etc

```
dictionary (x:xs) (y:ys) = do

if ys == [] then return(x:xs) else dictionary (x:xs)(ys)
   
if xs == [] then return(x:xs) else dictionary (xs)(y:ys)
```

This is the furthest ive come, and it doesnt work. i feel like im on the right track but

the argument is string -> string.

Comment: What are the expected arguments? What is the return type supposed to be?

Comment: What does each argument mean?

Comment: the argument is :: string -> string

Comment: One problem is that the function you have written has two arguments: `(x:xs)` and `(y:ys)`. And can you perhaps give some input and expected output examples? Is it supposed to be `dictionary "thanks" = "danke"`?

Comment: yes you are supposed to have    dictionary "input" = "output"

Comment: I've answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69224490/849891), see if it helps.